# How to apply some operations to special percentage of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to create, for example, one million objects but a certain percentage (`x%`) of them must be unique. I'm encountering an issue where the code doesn't accurately create the desired percentage of unique objects. This is especially apparent when the percentage is a decimal like `11.7%`.

Here is the code I've written:

```js
const createComponentsToAdd = () => {
    const uniqueCount = Math.floor(testConfig.percentOfUniqueComponents * testConfig.componentCount);
    const progressPoint = Math.round(testConfig.componentCount / uniqueCount);
    for (let i = 0; i <= testConfig.componentCount; i++) {
      const component = { ...componentToAdd };
      if (testConfig.percentOfUniqueComponents && i % progressPoint === 0) {
        component.originSource += " This made me unique " + Guid.newGuid().toString();
      }
      componentsToAdd.push(component);
    }
};
```

The issue seems to stem from the `progressPoint` calculation. When the `progressPoint` is less than 1, the `i % progressPoint === 0` condition is almost always true, and all components will be unique. This contradicts the desired percentage.

How can I fix this to accurately create the correct percentage of unique objects?

Comment: I don't think `i % progressPoint` does what you think it does. In JavaScript `%` is used to calculate the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

Comment: Is the _order_ in which you create those objects in any way relevant? Because if not ... `if(i < uniqueCount) { make unique object } else { make regular object }`

Comment: I understand, so if i want 25% of array progress point is 5. When i is divissible by 5 condition is true becouse remainder is 0

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, this might work